# mysql. Find record that has two fields between a value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two fields, `ip_start` and `ip_end`, and I want to find the record that has the given ip address between these two fields.

Say the table looks like this:

```
ip_start    ip_end  other data
123         778      xxx
500         800      yyy
```

I want to find the record that has 400.  If I say `select * from table where 400 <= ip_end`, I get both records. If I say `select * from table where 400 between ip_start and ip_end`, I get both.

What I want is "400 between ip_start and ip_end and ip_start is closest to ip_end". But of course there isn't such a query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Umm, 400 isn't between 500 and 800.  See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9394f2/1  What types are your fields?  Are they `INT`, `VARCHAR` or something else?  Are you *actually* searching for IP addresses, like `192.168.1.5`?  Or are you searching for numbers, like `400`?

Comment: What range do you expect to be returned for '550'? What range do you expect to be returned for '750'? It is possible to do 'closest'.

Comment: When you say "and ip_start is closest to ip_end" do you mean you want the record that has the smallest range between ip_start and ip_end that 400 is a subset of?

Answer (score 0):

"400 between ip_start and ip_end and ip_start is closest to ip_end"

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip_end >=  400 and ip_start <= 400 
 ORDER BY ip_end - ip_start
```

That means that:

1. ip_end is larger than 400
2. ip_start is less than 400
3. you care about the difference between ip_end and ip_start (subtraction)

If you only want one record, add `LIMIT 1` to the end

Answer (score 0):

You just need two constraints in the where clause, and an order by.

```
 select * from yourtable where ip_end >= 400 and ip_start <= 400 
                                  ORDER BY (ip_end - ip_start);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query does not include the ip_start column, so it is returning all the entries in the table that have their ip_end <= 400. You need to add the other constraint.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE( 
       ip_start >= 400 AND
       ip_end   <= 400
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the smallest ip range that your ip is a member of use this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 400 >= ip_start AND 400 <= ip_end 
ORDER BY ip_end - ip_start ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

will find all ranges that your ip is a member of, order by the smallest range and limit the query to a single record.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e63a0/2